# Change root state property from feature module ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx

**Problem Description**
I have a spinner module, which is displayed/hidden based on a loading property in my root state. This is placed inside AppComponent.

```
export interface AppState {
  loading: boolean
}
```

I have multiple lazily loaded feature modules, each of which fetch data through their own set of effects. While doing this, I would like to update the AppState.loading to true at the beginning of the effect and then set it back to false when the effect completes.

How do I do this?

**Work-around**
As a work-around, I am dispatching an action defined in root actions (which sets loading to true) before triggering my feature action, and then the feature effect returns an array of actions. One of these actions again belongs to root actions (which sets loading to false).

**service.ts**

```
public getMilestonesAction(q: string) {
  this.store.dispatch(AppActions.loadingAction({ loading: true})); // This belongs to root-actions
  return this.store.dispatch(CalendarActions.getEntriesAction({ q })); // This belongs to feature-actions
}
```

**effect.ts**

```
getMilestonesEffect$ = createEffect(() => this.action$
  .pipe(
    ofType(CalendarActions.getEntriesAction),
    mergeMap(action => this.calendarService.getMilestones(action.q)
    .pipe(
      switchMap((data: Milestone[]) => [AppActions.loadingAction({ loading: false }), CalendarActions.getEntriesSuccessAction({ milestones: data })]),
      catchError((error: any) => from([AppActions.loadingAction({ loading: false }), CalendarActions.getEntriesFailureAction( { error: this.getErrorMessage(error) })]))
    ))
  ));
```

Is this the correct approach to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct and you do it right.

`root` and `feature` only allows you to lazy load reducers and effects for modules that need them, but both of them have full access to the store and can use actions they need.

Angular recommends to have `core/feature/shared` groups of modules. In this case, the load action would be in `core` or `shared`, what you feel is the better fit.

Comment: Using common state inside a shared module seems a great suggestion. Thank you for that! I'll wait for some time to see if anyone comes with any other alternative. Else I will mark your response as the answer.